# SQL query to return a particular column or a default value in case of row not existing in the db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement of getting an employee id from department id (lets consider that one department will only contain 1 employee at most)

I can do something like below:

```
 Select emp_id from emp where dept_id = 101;
```

Now in case this row was not existing, I won't be getting any value.

However since I am using this query in PL/SQL layer, it will throw a NO_DATA_FOUND exception (when no employee exists in db)

Can you refactor this query to return some emp_id = -1 in case no employee exists in db.

i can do something like below (which results in 2 sql queries, so not efficient)

```
 select count(1) INTO temp_count from emp where dept_id = 101; -- or use an exists clause

 if (temp_count != 0)
    Select emp_id from emp where dept_id = 101;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select nvl(min(emp_id),-1) 
  from emp 
 where dept_id = 101;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clever.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the provided answer ,there are multiple ways you can address this requirement.

You can use `DECODE`,`COALESCE`,`NULLIF` like below :

```
Select COALESCE(emp_id,<default value>) from emp where dept_id = 101;
Select DECODE(emp_id,NULL,<default value>,emp_id) from emp where dept_id = 101;
```

Go through this Link [NULL-Related Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/null-related-functions) for more examples

Comment: None of the queries return -1, they return no row. See @peter Alexeev answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PL/SQL, presumably a function, why not just handle the no_data_found error, rather than faffing around with the sql statement and possibly making it less efficient?

E.g. something like:

```
create or replace function get_emp_id (p_dept_id number)
return number
is
  v_emp_id number;
begin
  select emp_id
  into   v_emp_id
  from   emp
  where  dept_id = p_dept_id;

  return v_emp_id;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    return -1;
end get_emp_id;
/
```

Comment: Putting logic in exception block generally doesn't make sense, is slower as well. Moreover what if more than 1 block can throw the same exception?

Comment: "Putting logic in exception block generally doesn't make sense" ... eh? Where did you get that idea from? Handling exception cases is precisely the reason why the exception block exists! And as for it being slower; is that really an issue (if, indeed, that is true) in this particular scenario? Would love to see your proof for this statement. And as for more than one block throwing the same exception ... that's what modularisation is for!

Comment: I will probably put in another question to verify this, if I am not able to find any resource to back up. (my statement comes from what I was told by others, and my knowledge of Java, which may or may not be applicable here)

Comment: @rents I guess it depends on how you use the query. If the no_data_found is a rare case, then having the exception handler handle, then doing the straight select and then jumping to the exception block is not going to cause much of a slow-down. If the no row returned is a common occurrence then I'd probably avoid using an implicit cursor at all, and instead use an explicit cursor with an open-fetch. That way, you can handle the cases where a row is returned vs not returned without having to a) amend the sql statement, potentially slowing it down for all queries and ...

Comment: @rents ... b) avoid a no_data_found exception. I agree that using the exception block as a sneaky form of `goto` is best avoided, though, but that's mainly for ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block for your problem :

`select t.emp_id
  from (select nvl(e.emp_id
                  ,-1) as emp_id
          from emp e
         where e.dept_id = 101) t
 where t.emp_id <> -1`

Comment: This doesn't output any row (even when I remove the last line i.e. the where condition) , did I miss anything?

Comment: You dont miss anything, there is no data e.dept_id = 101 for this condition.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I do want a return value for that case, that is the point of asking this question. Maybe the question description is not very clear.

Comment: I am understand, i will give another solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code block :

`select case
         when e.emp_id is null then
          -1
         else
          e.emp_id
       end as emp_id
  from emp e
 where e.dept_id = 101`

Comment: @rents you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code
Select nvl(emp_id,default_value) from emp where dept_id = 101;
Select DECODE(emp_id,NULL,default_value,emp_id) from emp where dept_id = 101;